# For loop to sleep and execute my code with time delay

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to create a game.  I used lot of methods but I get bad results.

```
for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);             
}
```

I use this code to create my sprite images.  What I want is to execute the same code again and again, every 8 seconds.  I used:

```
for (int me = 0; me < 10; me++){
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);             
    }
    Thread.sleep(8000);
}
```

I thought this makes the for loop to run slow.  But what happened was my Sprites also started to move very slow that is it change it's position for every 2 sec .. since i have 2000ms sleep :(

Thank you u all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please edit your code in the future so it shows up correctly.  Always make sure to put a language tag on the question as well.  I assume this is Java.  If this is Android, please add an Android tag.  It's also always good to show what research you have done.  What documentation you have read.  What else you have tried.  Best of luck!

Comment: ok here after i will do it ty :)

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is fast sprite drawing but a *constant* rate of frames per seconds. :)
to solve the issue use your OS real time clock to wait for the exact amount of time!

something like:

```
while(1)
{
    t1 = now();
    draw_screen();
    game_logic();
    get_user_input();
    t2 = now();

    sleep(); // here wait for ((1/fps)-(t2-t1)) sec.
}
```

this will force your game to run at a given fps rate. Obviously this approach doesn't cover the case in which the drawing routine takes longer than the actual 1/fps time window; you'll need to implement some sort of frame dropping technique

Comment: my game runs smooth and well but what i want is i want to create more and more images to the screen in a regular time interval

Comment: Note that on android, you cannot sleep in the UI thread and you cannot change the UI directly from a background thread, but must push work for the updates to the UI thread.

Comment: ok.. if you wanna draw a sprite let's say every 1500ms (1.5 sec) you could do something like if(now() % 1500 == 0) drawit(); where now() returns the epoch in milliseconds